# Loop through and download multiple CSVs from Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, export-to-csv

I have the following code which I am using to download a CSV of the data to a file called Out of Area.csv

```html
<?php

// START EXPORT OF LTHT DATA //
exportMysqlToCsv('Out of Area.csv');


// export csv
function exportMysqlToCsv($filename = 'Out of Area.csv')
{

   $conn = dbConnection();
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM MDSData WHERE Downloaded IS NULL ORDER BY RegisteredCCG";

    // Gets the data from the database
    $result = $conn->query($sql_query);

    $f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
    $first = true;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($first) {
            fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
            $first = false;
        }
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    } // end while


$sql_query = "UPDATE MDSData SET Downloaded='YES' WHERE Downloaded IS NULL";

    // Gets the data from the database
    if ($conn->query($sql_query) === TRUE) {
} else {
}
     $conn->close();


    $size = ftell($f);
    rewind($f);

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    // Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    fpassthru($f);
    exit;

}



// db connection function
function dbConnection(){
    $servername = "servername";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    return $conn;
}

  header('location:csv-upload-mds.php?week='.$SelectedWeek);

?>
```

However I have a column in my table called **'TownName'** and I would like to loop through creating a CSV Named **'Out of Area - The Town Name Here.csv'** for example  **'Out of Area - Berkshire.csv'**

Currently i've got to the stage where I can make it download 1 file with all the data in, however my issue comes when trying to download multiple files. Even if I duplicate the exportMysqlToCsv() call I get an error as this function can only be called once. So I need to put the loop inside an if statement I guess...

My thoughts are something like the following

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM MDSData WHERE Downloaded IS NULL GROUP BY REGISTERED CCG"
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

// Now I've looped through each CCG for each one I can set the file name and add the data to the file.

$filename = "Out of Area - " . $row["TownName"]. ".csv";
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM MDSData WHERE Downloaded IS NULL ORDER BY RegisteredCCG";

// Gets the data from the database
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);

$f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
$first = true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($first) {
        fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
        $first = false;
    }
    fputcsv($f, $row);
} // end while of inside loop
} // end while of 1st SQL query
```

However whilst I belive my idea is solid, I'm struggling to put it all together and looking for a little help.

Thanks

Comment: You can not send multiple different resources in response to _one single_ HTTP request to begin with.

Comment: well that explaines a lot...thanks. Is there any other way of getting mutilple downloads of files then?

Comment: Either you pack your data in some kind of archive format (tar, zip, …) on the server, and then download only that one single file, that can be unpacked to get the individual files again afterwards on the client; or you have to have the client make multiple requests - perhaps in some automated fashion, like having a couple of links that get a “click” triggered via JS or something.

Comment: No internet surfer (including you) managed to download multiple files thru one click so far - each download needs to be requested on its own.